# Storing output from mathematica loop in file

Tags: mathematica-8

I am running a for-loop in mathematica on a relatively fine grid for different parameterizations. The loop is rather time-consuming and I want to automatize it so that I can run it over night. Therefore I would create another for - loop over the vector of parameters. But I don't know how to store the output from each run of that loop in a separate file. Basically, I want mathematica to create a folder labeled with the parameter value and to store the output from the for-loop in that folder. Is that possible and can anyone advise me how to program that?